# Why does my nib's window close immediately?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a nib that I load the usual way

`[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"AuthorizationWindow" owner:self];`

and I see the window show on the screen briefly, and using NSLog() I can confirm that -awakeFromNib is called, but I can't figure out why the window does not stay on the screen. I had it working correctly for a bit, but now I'm not sure what I changed that messed it up. Thoughts of where to start looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess your window is being deallocated (or if under GC, collected) right out from under you.  There are about a million possible reasons for this (none of which we can diagnose from one line of code), but there mere fact you're using +loadNibNamed:owner: is a warning flag.  The reason is that items instantiated in nibs follow the same memory management rules as the rest of Cocoa; if you want them to stick around, you have to retain them (or in GC, keep a reference to them).  NSWindowController (and NSViewController too) has some special nib-handling code so that it retains all the top-level objects in its nib when it loads, so that they'll stick around as long as it does*.  However, if you don't use that, you have to do all that manually.

The real solution is: Don't use +loadNibNamed:owner:.  Instead, create an NSWindowController subclass and set up its -init method like so:

```
@implementation AuthorizationWindowController
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"AuthorizationWindow"];
    if (self == nil) return nil;
    // any other initialization code
    return self;
}
```

*It also has special code to handle bindings-induced retain cycles that would normally cause it to leak, which is quite a bit more difficult to write yourself.  Yet one more reason to use NSWindowController.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a closer look at the object you are using to load the nib (`self`, in the code you provided). Since it is the owner of the window, the window will be released when that object is released.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had enabled GC and that did it. Will give the window controller method a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In windowViewController header file type this:

```
@property (strong) NSWindowController *wc;
```

in implementation:
synthesise wc at top

```
-(id)init{
    wc = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindowController"];
    if(wc == nil){
        return nil;
    }

    return wc;
}
```

When you want to make the window visible:

```
- (IBAction)mnuNewImageClicked:(id)sender {
    NewWindowController *ivc = [[NewWindowController alloc] init];
    [ivc showWindow:self];
}
```

This worked for me.